# Can I query Microsoft SQL Server using pure Python?

Tags: python, sql-server

I need to query SQL Server from Python in a machine that I don't have admin rights. I can't install drivers in it. I'll query mainly from a Linux machine, but it would be nice if I it can also be used from Windows during development.

I want to make a simple query in MS SQL Server with a Python lib. A lib that doesn't need any driver installed in the Operating System. Is it possible? Everything that I found asks to install the Microsoft driver in the host OS.

Comment: How would that work? You would just be reinventing the wheel i.e. writing your own driver. Which would be a massive amount of work and I'm not even sure the API is documented.

Comment: Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @Parfait I think now the question better describes my problem.

Comment: @DaleK  The protocol is at least documented, but implementing it is not trivial. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/b46a581a-39de-4745-b076-ec4dbb7d13ec

Answer (score 1):

A quick search turns up [pydts](https://pypi.org/project/python-tds/) but it's not supported by Microsoft and I have no idea how widely adopted it is or if it's being actively maintained.  Here's the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/denisenkom/pytds).